# how to check which collection is taking how much time to load in a function in magento 1.9

Tags: model, sql, code, optimization

I am writing a backend function for loading a profile on android app, want to figure out why its slow , and taking more time to load so want to debug the load time of each query in function how can I ?

```
  $collection = Mage::getModel("manager/campus")->getCollection()
                                                              ->addFieldToFilter('regionalmanager',array('finset' => $arr))
                                                              ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));
                foreach ($collection as $collegename)
                {
                    array_push($college, $collegename->getId());
                    array_push($colnames, $collegename->getName());
                    if ($collegename->getCampusmanager() != "")
                    {
                        $ids = explode(",", $collegename->getCampusmanager());
                        $campusmanager = array_merge($campusmanager, $ids);

                    }
                }
                $customerids = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection()
                                                                  ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
                                                                  ->addAttributeToFilter('grisk_college_new_id', array('in' =>$college))
                                                                  ->getAllIds();

                $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                                                      ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',array('in' => $customerids));

                $delayedcollectioncount = "SELECT * FROM ".$resource->getTableName('customer/customer').










                $delayedcollectioncount = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")
                                                                    ->getCollection()
                                                                    ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname, entity_id')
                                                                    ->addAttributeToFilter('grisk_college_new_id', array('in' =>$college))
                                                                    ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', array('in' => array(4,5)))
                                                                    ->addAttributeToFilter('assigned_campus_manager', array('null' => true), 'left')
                                                                    ->addAttributeToFilter('physical_verify', array('null' => true), 'left')
                                                                    ->addFieldToFilter('grisk_pv_upload_date', array('lt' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($configValue))))
                                                                    ->addAttributeToSort('grisk_pv_upload_date', 'DESC')
                                                                    ->count();
                //Collection by status.
                $verifycollectioncount = $this->getVerifyListForAsm($CollegeIds,$page);            
                $verifycollectioncount = $verifycollectioncount->count();

                $penddingconfirmation = $this->getPendingConfirmationForAsm($CollegeIds,$custid, $page);         
                $penddingconfirmation = $penddingconfirmation->count();

                $reverifycollectioncount = $this->getReverifyCollectionForAsm($CollegeIds,$custid, $page);
                $reverifycollectioncount = $reverifycollectioncount->count();

                $OrderStudent = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection()
                                                                  ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname, entity_id')
                                                                  ->addAttributeToFilter('grisk_college_new_id',array('in' => $college))
                                                                  ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', array('in' => array(4,5,6)));

                $HighPri = $custidArray = $OrderFull = $OrderPPnOA = $OrderPPnOP =  array();
                foreach ($OrderStudent as $each)
                {
                    $custidArray[] = $each->getId();
                }
                    /** **High priority*  **/
                $totorders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
                                                ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                                                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('in' => $custidArray))
                                                ->addFieldToFilter('payment_status', array('in' => array('Paid','Partial')))
                                                ->addFieldToFilter('loan_document_status', 'Not signed')
                                                ->addFieldToFilter('facility_loan_type', 'Facility');
                foreach($totorders as $orders):

                    $LfaStatus = '';
                    $checkLfa  = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load($orders->getCustomerId());
                    $LfaStatus = $checkLfa->getGriskFacilityStatus();
                    if($LfaStatus==NULL || $LfaStatus=='' || $LfaStatus=='Not signed')
                    {
                        $HighPri[$orders->getId()]=$orders->getCustomerId();
                    }else
                    {
                        $orders->setLoanDocumentStatus($LfaStatus);
                        $orders->save();
                    }
```

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9288945/5393211

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 ways as per my knowledge. May be more... not sure though.

### Magento's Way

1) Go to `lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` set `$_debug` to `TRUE` and set `$_logAllQueries` to `TRUE`. Now in this `var/debug/pdo_mysql.log` file all your queries will be logged and you will know which is taking how much time.

2) Enable compiler from backend and it will show you per controller basis.(Never used it though and not sure properly.)

### PHP's way

3) Use

```
$start = microtime(true); // when function starts
       $end = microtime(true); // when function ends
      $end - $start = will give you exact time a function is taking to load.
```

Comment: diffrence is blank

Answer (score 0):

```
                     $my_timer = microtime();
                    $time_parts = explode(' ', $my_timer);
                    $time_right_now = $time_parts[1] + $time_parts[0];
                    $starting_time = $time_right_now;


// write your function or collection ;


 $my_timer = microtime();
                    $time_parts = explode(' ', $my_timer);
                    $time_right_now = $time_parts[1] + $time_parts[0];
                    $finishing_time = $time_right_now;
                    $total_time_in_secs = round(($finishing_time - $starting_time), 4);
                    echo 'Page generated in new mycollection count'.$total_time_in_secs.' seconds.';
```